# getting error while magento composer install

Tags: composer

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
  The checksum verification of the file failed (downloaded from https://repo.
  magento.com/archives/magento/google-shopping-ads/magento-google-shopping-ad
  s-3.0.1.0.zip)
```

Everything was running smooth untill I got this error and cannot install composer

```
Autoload error
Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.
```

Comment: did you run the composer install in the magento 2 root directory?

Comment: yes in root directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original issue is this

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25028

```
  - Installing magento/google-shopping-ads (3.0.1): Downloading (100%)         

  [UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
  The checksum verification of the file failed (downloaded from https://repo.  
  magento.com/archives/magento/google-shopping-ads/magento-google-shopping-ad  
  s-3.0.1.0.zip)
```

Solution

```
sed -i 's/5f5929ef9f2ec4ca048a2add261d22c92807630f/ce31e720d60451784b9fdb3769e43e149f50d436/g' composer.lock
```

Then run composer install

However your second issue I'm unsure. Looks like composer is broken.

Have you tried `composer dump-autoload` in web root

Comment: Thanks bro you saved me